# Change the values in a dataframe with conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

I've got a dataframe like the following example:

```
df:               df(i want to have):
0                 0
50                1
50                1
1                 1
50                0
50                0
50                0
50                0
0                 0
50                1
1                 1
```

I want the values between 0 and 50 to be 1 and the values between 1 and 0 to be 0
Is there an easy solution to my problem?

Comment: How about values between 0 and 0 and values between 1 and 1?

Comment: To create code blocks wrap with ``` or select text, `ctrl`+`k`

Comment: `df.where(df.isin([0,1])).bfill()`

Comment: Thank you Quang that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df["column"][i] == 50:
        df["column"][i] = 1
```